# How to return users and friends in one result in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have query like this:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[S:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[H:Has]-(FU:User)-[FS:Shout]->(FP:Post)
WHERE FU.user_id=2
return U.username, P.post, FU.username, FP.post
```

Query above will return result like:

```
U.username  P.post  FU.username FP.post
rio         lala    murey       nana
rio         lala    murey       hi
rio         hanson  murey       nana
rio         hanson  murey       hi
```

But I want to return result like:

```
U.username  P.post
murey       hi
rio         hanson
murey       nana
rio         lala
```

and the result I want above is ordered by `post_id desc`

is there a way to return the result like I want above?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the query is creating a cartesian product! Try breaking it up using WITH statements and see if it works..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Union](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-union.html):

```
MATCH (FU:User {user_id: 2})-[FS:Shout]->(FP:Post)
RETURN FU.username as name, FP.post as post
UNION
MATCH 
(U:User)-[S:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[H:Has]-(FU:User {user_id: 2})
return U.username as name, P.post as post
```

Union does not support an ordering of the entire result yet- perhaps you can sort in your application.

Comment: nah I already thought that but I think `UNION` is not effiecient and it is already explained in [http://jexp.de/blog/2014/02/state-of-the-cypher-union/](Michael Hunger Blog). The problem was it returned too much (unrelated) data. As you can see the second statement looks good, whereas the first is a full graph scan of the database, finding all `Shout` relationships. Not what we want. And I already tried using `collection`, it works but the problem is in ordering.